# How do I get VsCode to auto import correctly from an es6 module?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, es6-modules

lib1.js is an es6 module

```
export function greet() {
   console.log('Hello from Greet');
}
```

In main.js call `greet()`. VsCode auto import will add an import for

```
const { greet } = require('./lib1');
```

...instead of

```
import { greet } from './lib1';
```

jsconfig.json

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
   },
   "module": "es2015"
}
```

How do I fix this?

P.S. I've tried `"type": "module"` in package.json too.

Comment: Have you tried adding `"esModuleInterop":true` in `compilerOptions`?

Comment: Yes tried that too. It adds the same CommonJS style import.

Answer (score 4):

in most case , it will work fine with a `jsconfig` at root.
ex: jsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2020",
        "module": "esnext",
        "jsx": "react",
        "checkJs": true,
        "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
        "esModuleInterop": true, // force import
        "moduleResolution": "node",

        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, // force import
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

but if for any reason **you use also a** `tsConfig` in your root (example for generate d.ts from js), you will need to add `"allowJs": true`
ex: tsConfig.json

```json
{
    "include": ["src/"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "ES6",
        "jsx": "react",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "checkJs": true,
// default false, and will break jsconfig import, because with ts, vscode will think all js file are for nodejs, and no sugar import for nodejs.
        "allowJs": true,

        "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "allowUnreachableCode": true,
        "outDir": "types/",
        "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
        "declaration": true
    }
}
```

After all edit, you should restart ts server.
type `restart` for English, you should found it and it can take time.
[image]